# Can't Copy to Clipboard from Vim

Tags: debian, vim, vimrc, linux-mint

I'm running Vim 7.3 under Linux Mint 13 (using MATE) and I'm not able to save text to the system clipboard. I run Vim in the terminal and copy text from the terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>INSERT</kbd>. When I select text in Vim (either with the mouse or in visual mode), <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>INSERT</kbd> doesn't copy any text. In addition when I right-click, Copy is grayed out. Further, I can't write to the system buffer by yanking to the corresponding register using vim commands. However, I'm able to paste while in insert mode (using <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>INSERT</kbd> or right-click paste). I'm also able to copy text directly from the terminal using the same technique, just not text from Vim.

Here is my [current ~/.vimrc](http://pastie.org/4065198). The relevant part is most likely `set clipboard=autoselect,unnamed,exclude:cons\|linux`. If I put `finish` at the top of my ~/.vimrc, I have the same issue, so I think the line is wrong, but I've tried `set clipboard=unnamed` and had the same behavior.

Could there be another config file affecting Vim's behavior? How can I change my ~/.vimrc to allow me to copy text from Vim?

Comment: Dead link for the current vimrc.

Comment: Amplifying @questionto42standswithUkraine's comment: the efficacy of the question and answers is reduced significantly without seeing the vimrc contents

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I believe your copy problem is caused by:

```
mouse=a
```

in your .vimrc
This sets your vim into visual mode whenever you select something with the mouse.
And for some mad reason one is not allowed to copy when in visual mode.
You can get around it by holding down shift when selecting text not to go into visual mode allowing you to use the copy menu.

or you could change to:

```
:set mouse=v
```

and copy will work again.

Add `:set mouse=v` to your `~/.vimrc` file if you want it to be permanent (create `~/.vimrc` if it does not exist yet).

Comment: While this might actually solve their problem an explanation of *why it works* would be more useful.  Without it your answer is just telling someone to [Press the Green Button Twice](http://blog.serverfault.com/2011/06/09/press-the-green-button-twice/) - It might work, it might not, but it doesn't enlighten them.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. The explanation you added after voretaq7's comment helped a lot, too!

Comment: This works for Cygwin, too.

Comment: This mode will highlight everything, so if I want to copy a few lines, I'm also copying line numbers and all the empty space after each line until the end of the screen. Is there a way to only have it select the relevant content (which is how highlight works when `mouse=a`)?

Comment: Good answer. Just a plus: more mouse modes here `:help mouse`

Comment: Just the tip of holding shift while highlighting was spot on. I use the primary (highlight + middle mouse click) copy/paste all the time. Thanks.

Comment: After being frustrated by this for YEARS, you have saved me a lot of future misery!

Comment: no matter what I do the mouse defaults away from whatever I select.

Comment: Thanks, solved my pain. What I don't understand is why Vim (8.1 for me) sets `mouse=a` as default? This is very frustrating.

Answer (score 20):

`sudo apt-get install vim-gtk` will likely solve this problem for other Googlers.

Good ol' terminal-style vim doesn't have access to the clipboard, which is a part of the X windows system.  Installing `vim-gtk` gives vim the access that it needs to modify and view the clipboard.

Comment: Works!  On Debian Buster (now in testing) I installed vim-gtk and then my command line vim in xterm allowed me to use the `*` and `+` buffers to access the x window buffers.  The vim-gtk installation uses the Debian alternatives to set `vim -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk`.

Answer (score 1):

just `gvim` on arch linux if anyone wants to know. Also, have a look at `neovim` (and `python-neovim` && `python2-neovim` for You Complete Me support, etc).

Comment: Try using gvim via ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Using Pop!_OS 21.04 and ran into this issue.

Per [this github commen](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/issues/12514#issuecomment-647130976)t, installing `xclip` worked fixed this for me.

`sudo apt install xclip`

Answer (score 0):

The terminal doesn't know anything about vim selections, so don't expect it to be any help. You will need vim to be built against X (e.g. `gvim -v`), and then yank to and put from the `+` register.

Comment: The `vim-gtk` package in Ubuntu contains clipboard support (even when executed as `vim` in a terminal).

Comment: Agreed and confirmed on Debian Buster (now in testing) I installed vim-gtk and then my command line vim in xterm allowed me to use the * and + buffers to access the x window buffers. The vim-gtk installation uses the Debian alternatives to set vim -> /usr/bin/vim.gtk.

Answer (score 0):

I use this [plugin](https://github.com/christoomey/vim-system-copy). Works even if you have `-xterm_cliboard`or `-clipboard`. The mapping is also very simple, just `cp` and `cv` for copy and paste.

Answer (score 0):

On the question text at first:
I do not believe that you cannot select and copy with the mouse "what you see" in the window since I have the same issue like you, it seems, and I *can* do so, but I cannot mark more than the window and copy that, only then, `Copy` is grayed out. Well, we might have different problems here. Still, this tool trick should help as well:

##### Alacritty

You need a terminal program that embeds vim into the terminal text,
for example the **"Alacritty" terminal**. With that, you can just zoom out and copy with Ctrl+Shift+C or your clipboard key.

You can also try the vim mode: press *Ctrl+Shift+Space*, you can then move through the console history and mark what you need, if you need all, type the vim command *ggVG*, afterwards, you can paste it in a text file and then back in terminal, you get out of the vim mode by pressing *Ctrl+Shift+Space* again.

##### Tmux + clipboard (in Alacritty or another terminal)

If you need to copy large text that you cannot copy with the zoom out trick of Alacritty, install tmux and a clipboard like xclip or xsel. Tmux is not a terminal on its own. Try its commands in Alacritty or any other terminal.

```shell
sudo apt-get update -y 
sudo apt-get install -y xclip
```

And put this in your ~/.tmux.conf to bind y to the xclip copy:

```shell
bind -T copy-mode-vi y send -X copy-pipe "xclip -selection c"
```

With the tmux shortcut *Ctrl+B-->[* you can start marking whatever you want with Space and then Arrows or picture up/down. After you marked all of the needed text, press y that you bound to "copy to xclip". That makes it possible to copy anything, no matter what size.

See also [How to copy multi-page text from the terminal into the clipboard?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/698525/442338).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same trouble in nvim on macOS, and got it working by running this (no need to modify it, just press `:` then run as-is):

```
set mouse=
```

After that I could copy/paste from nvim in the terminal as expected.

I found this information [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13099/not-able-to-copy-from-terminal-when-using-vim-from-homebrew-on-macos#comment22506_13112)